# R plumber - how to caution against code injection

Tags: r, api, security, code-injection, plumber

This question is focused on the R `plumber` package, however, can be interesting/useful on its own.

I'm working on very simple `plumber` API calls, for example,

```
function(key) {
  tryCatch({
     if(key == "ABCD"){system('./script.sh', intern = T)}
  }, error = function(e){return(NULL)})
}
```

Which will execute a `script.sh` *with superuser permissions* after receiving a specific REST call. At the moment, the idea is to use this script internally - essentially, clicking a button will invoke a call with the specific key.

However, since the code will called under elevated permissions, **my question is this** -- when specifying a function to be executed with free input parameters like this, **how can I make sure that the script will execute only what's specified and nothing more?**

I'm not well versed in R code injection, but are there any known ways to secure against `key` values like `ABCD\") system('...'); #` or similar (this is just a bad example, but I assume there could exist some known vulnerabilities)?

Or is base R secure enough in cases like these?

---

*Side note*: Currently such code would be used internally only, however, I don't feel good leaving open elevated access like this even in a controlled environment.

Comment: IMO your best bet is to check the input and handle it manually before triggering the script. If you're working inside a dockerized container, running as a root shouldn't be that of a problem.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik would using ``match.arg(key)`` and specifying possible choices in the function definition be a good solution? E.g., ``function(key = c("V1","V2",...))``.

Comment: As they say about the proverbial cat, there are many ways to skin it. What is the "correct" way will depend on your use-case, environment and skills.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik True, however, I'm sure in my case it would suffice to hear about the best practices. It's easy to answer "it depends", however, while true, it conveys no new information.

Comment: Can't speak for other, but I would need to hear about who will be using the app, what is the use case, what might be the needs in the future, what will be the deployment environment... This all plays into how I would tackle the problem. Sorry for being so vague.